# Python GUI callback functions

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a Python program that calculates Miles Per Gallon(MPG) using a GUI.
The code below contains a function called calc_mpg that is meant to use the input from the main function 'miles_entry' Entry and 'gallons_entry' Entry to calculate the miles per gallon of a vehicle when the 'calc_button' is clicked.

When the button is clicked I am given an error saying that 'miles_entry' is not defined. Is there a way in which this code must be restructured or reworked to run as intended.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

def main():
     main_window = tkinter.Tk()
     upper_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window)
     lower_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window)

     label1 = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='This program calculates MPG')

     miles_prompt = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='How many miles can be 
     driven with full gastank?')
     miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(upper_frame, width = 10)
     gallons_prompt = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='How many gallons of 
     gas can the tank hold?')
     gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(upper_frame, width = 10)

     miles_prompt.pack()
     miles_entry.pack()
     gallons_prompt.pack()
     gallons_entry.pack()

     calc_button = tkinter.Button(lower_frame, text='Calculate MPG', 
     command=calc_mpg)
     quit_button = tkinter.Button(lower_frame, text='Quit', 
     command=main_window.destroy)



    upper_frame.pack()
    lower_frame.pack()
    calc_button.pack()
    quit_button.pack()
    tkinter.mainloop()


def calc_mpg():
    miles = float(miles_entry.get())
    gallons = float(gallons_entry.get())

    mpg = miles / gallons

    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('The miles per gallon for this vehicle is:' 
   + mpg + 'mpg.') 



main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You hit the nail on why `tk` applications are usually wrapped in a class. By using a class, you can save persistently objects and use them across methods:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class main:
    def __init__(self):
        main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        upper_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window)
        lower_frame = tkinter.Frame(main_window)

        label1 = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='This program calculates MPG')

        miles_prompt = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='How many miles can be driven with full gastank?')
        self.miles_entry = tkinter.Entry(upper_frame, width = 10)
        gallons_prompt = tkinter.Label(upper_frame, text='How many gallons of gas can the tank hold?')
        self.gallons_entry = tkinter.Entry(upper_frame, width = 10)

        miles_prompt.pack()
        self.miles_entry.pack()
        gallons_prompt.pack()
        self.gallons_entry.pack()

        calc_button = tkinter.Button(lower_frame, text='Calculate MPG', 
        command=self.calc_mpg)
        quit_button = tkinter.Button(lower_frame, text='Quit', 
        command=main_window.destroy)

        upper_frame.pack()
        lower_frame.pack()
        calc_button.pack()
        quit_button.pack()
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def calc_mpg(self):
        miles = float(self.miles_entry.get())
        gallons = float(self.gallons_entry.get())

        mpg = miles / gallons

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Some info!",message='The miles per gallon for this vehicle is:' 
       + str(mpg) + 'mpg.') 

main()
```

I added `self` to refer to both entries, so you can use them in your other method (variables by default only live in the function they are defined). Also note:

1. Your forgot to convert `mpg` back to a string in the info box
2. The info box first argument is the title, not the content

If the `self` notation or classes are unfamiliar, you should study this up prior to creating your `tk` apps.

Answer (score 0):

The miles_entry and the gallon_entry in the main() scope, they are not visible in calc_mpg().
@kabanus is right.
Another workaroaund is using partial() from the functools module. It make possible to pass arguments to the callback:

```
from functools import partial
...
calc_button = tkinter.Button(lower_frame, text='Calculate MPG', command=partial(calc_mpg,miles_entry,gallons_entry) )
...
def calc_mpg(miles_entry,gallons_entry):
  ...
```